# jQuery - Dynamic DataTable - Data JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to create a DataTable with Dynamic Columns And Data. 
**My html code:**

```
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display">
    </table>
</body>
```

**My data.json:**

```
{
    "Category": {
        "0": "Bags",
        "1": "Shoes",
        "2": "School",
        "3": "Video-Games",
        "4": "PC-Games"
    },
    "Price": {
        "0": 10,
        "1": 20,
        "2": 30,
        "3": 40,
        "4": 50
    }
}
```

In this point, i want Category and Price to be the columns.

**My js code is:**

```
$(document).ready(function name(params) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var columns = Object.keys(response).map(function (key) {
                return { title: key };
            });

            $('#example').DataTable({
                data: Object.values(response),
                columns: columns
            });
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
});
```

I want the below result 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkHuu.png]

But i recieve this: 
[image]

Comment: Map value of each object as value:value something like this:
`{'bag':'10', 'shoes':'20'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation suggests a slightly different `data` and `columns` formats.
for each column, you have to specify the [data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Objects) to use and its [title](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title)
And each row has to be an object keyed by the column `data` it was assigned.

I admit that DataTables documentation is a bit unintuitive to navigate... But it is extensively complete.

Below is the code you should have in the Ajax `success` callback.

```js
const data = {
  "Category": {
    "0": "Bags",
    "1": "Shoes",
    "2": "School",
    "3": "Video-Games",
    "4": "PC-Games"
  },
  "Price": {
    "0": 10,
    "1": 20,
    "2": 30,
    "3": 40,
    "4": 50
  }
}

const columnKeys = Object.keys(data)
const columns = columnKeys.map((column) => ({title: column, data: column}))
const rowKeys = Object.keys(data[columnKeys[0]])
const rows = rowKeys.map((rowKey) => {
  const row = {}
  columnKeys.forEach((columnKey) => row[columnKey] = data[[columnKey]][rowKey])
  
  return row
})

//console.log(columnKeys)
console.log(columns)
//console.log(rowKeys)
console.log(JSON.stringify(rows))

$('#example').DataTable({
  data: rows,
  columns: columns
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table id="example" class="display">
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring a dynamic table, you need to return each column and data with for and push them to the columns.

```
 var data = {
  "Category": {
    "0": "Bags",
    "1": "Shoes",
    "2": "School",
    "3": "Video-Games",
    "4": "PC-Games"
  },
  "Price": {
    "0": 10,
    "1": 20,
    "2": 30,
    "3": 40,
    "4": 50
  }
}
 var columns = [];
 columnNames = Object.keys(data[0]);
  for (var i in columnNames) {
     columns.push({
         data: columnNames[i],
         title: columnNames[i]
     });
 }
$('#example').DataTable({
   "data": data,
  "columns": columns
});


  <table id="example" class="table table-borderless table-hover" data-toggle="data-table" style="width:100%;" width="100%"> </table>
```

its easy way.